# MySQL Connector returning "None" when there is data

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm using Python MySQL connector and I know there is a table named "users" in this db. I keep running into this issue no matter what I try (show tables, `select * from users`, etc). I even created a table with MySQL connector but it still returns "None".

I tried:

```py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname

import mysql.connector
from dotenv import load_dotenv


dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), 'usersSQL.env')

load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

DB_HOST = os.environ.get("DB_HOST")
DB_USER = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
DB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD")
DB_NAME = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")

usersDB = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=DB_HOST,
    user=DB_USER,
    password=DB_PASSWORD,
    database=DB_NAME
)

cursor = usersDB.cursor()

print(cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES"))
```

It returned:

```
    admin@localhost:/var/www/environments$ sudo python3 index.py 
    None
```

Comment: That's because `cursor.execute()` does not directly return the results of the query.  The results are stored internally in the cursor object, and you have to call `cursor.fetchall()` to fetch them.

Comment: Why did you think `cursor.execute()` returns the query results?  Did you see some example of doing it that way?

Comment: @JohnGordon If they have previous experience with `SQLAlchemy`, perhaps working with a `sqlite3` database, that would be the expected behavior